# How did Admiral Trench survive his bridge exploding in Star Wars: the Clone Wars?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars

In the Clone Wars episode "Cat and Mouse" we are introduced to a thrilling new character: Admiral Trench. Unfortunately, not unlike Darth Maul, he dies before the character does much. But also like Darth Maul, he returns later: in season six of the series. It is obvious to the viewers that Admiral Trench had died when the bridge of his flagship was destroyed by tracking torpedos.

Answer (score 1):

### Main (Disney) canon

**We don't know.** From the fact that he turns up in a subsequent episode with very substantial injuries it can be surmised that he received these during his unlikely escape but aside from that, there's no other explanation offered as to *how* it happened. It's certainly not the first time we've seen a flag officer survive their ship exploding in a [handy escape pod](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Stealth_Strike) though.

### Legends Canon

The [Star Wars: Essential Guide to Warfare](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Essential_Guide_to_Warfare) doesn't specifically confirm how Trench survived a point blank volley of his own missiles, but it does talk about his prior escape from the destruction of his earlier ship. Evidently, his armour and physiology make him well-nigh unkillable.

> The Republic believed Trench was dead, but he managed to survive
>   thanks to a pressure suit of Andoan mineral-fish armor and his own
>   tough Harch hide. More than a decade later he reappeared, commanding
>   the Separatist blockade of Christophsis from the Invincible.